# Grails 3.0 error when displaying encoding views

Tags: grails, encoding, utf-8, grails-3.0

I am trying to create a Grails project with version 3.0.4, and something goes wrong on encoding:

Two GSPs with same content:

views > index.gsp: 
 
views > domain > show.gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
çççççççç óóóó úúúúúú ááá´´aááááá´´a´´´ççççç
    </body>
</html>
```

**Result** views > index.gsp:
çççççççç óóóó úúúúúú ááá´´aááááá´´a´´´ççççç

**Result** views > domain > show.gsp:
�������� ���� ������ ��ᴴa����ᴴa��������

Does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution on this link: http://grailsbrasil.com.br/post/show/3032

On IntelliJ, right click on gsp file > file encoding > utf-8